# Parsing a file with readlines and split function in python

Tags: python, parsing, readline

I have files I'm trying to parse. I want to print the date_of_birth on each line. The code below only returns the first line. I don't want to use readlines, as some of my files are very large.

```
HEADER: Date_of_birth, ID, First_Name, Last_Name
1/1/1970, 1, John, Smith
12/31/1969, 2, Peter, Smith
```

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readline().split[0]
    print(lines)
```

Comment: "I don't want to use readlines, as some of my files are very large." But you do want to read the entire file contents, and display it all on the terminal?

Comment: Does the word "HEADER:" actually appear in the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the `csv` module, though you have a slightly odd file format because it starts with `"HEADER: "` followed by the actual headers that you care about.  Maybe just read in those initial 8 bytes, verify that they actually contain the string `"HEADER: "` but otherwise discard them, then pass the open file handle to `csv` to parse the rest of the file.

Here's a simple example, which you might want to tweak to do more graceful handling of any errors:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:

    start_bytes = f.read(8)
    assert(start_bytes == 'HEADER: ')

    c = csv.reader(f)

    header_row = next(c)
    column_number = header_row.index('Date_of_birth')

    for row in c:
        print(row[column_number])
```

Update: thanks to another contributor for suggesting `csv.DictReader`. Similarly it seems that you can instantiate this with a file object positioned at some non-zero offset to discard the initial bytes containing `"HEADER: "` from the start of the file.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:

    start_bytes = f.read(8)
    assert(start_bytes == 'HEADER: ')

    c = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in c:
        print(row['Date_of_birth'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my mistake
Check this

```
dates = []
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        dates.append(row.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print(line['Date_of_birth'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `readline` function returns only one line at a time, so you have to use a while loop to read the lines:

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    dates = []
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:  # if line is blank, there are no more lines
            break  # stop the loop
        dates.append(line.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first row does not actually contain what you show as the `Header`, i.e. `Date_of_birth, ID, First_Name, Last_Name`,  then:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Date_of_birth', 'ID', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name']
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in rdr:
       date_of_birth = row['Date_of_birth']
       print(date_of_birth)
```

Otherwise:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rdr:
       date_of_birth = row['Date_of_birth']
       print(date_of_birth)
```

If the file's first row actually contains `HEADER: Date_of_birth, ID, First_Name, Last_Name`, then you must use the first alternative code but add logic to skip the first row.

My answer would have been 60% shorter had you been 10% clearer.